how to remove gazebo Fortress
I don't even know when it was installed but when I try to uninstall it with sudo apt remove ignition-fortress && sudo apt autoremove, it still exists and prevents me from running any other gazebo version.
I'm using ROS2-Humble.


Try sudo apt remove ignition* or even sudo apt remove ign*, but check the list of packages that will be removed before acknowledging.
